# Trigger another Gradle task from custom plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I've created a custom gradle plugin (for multi-module project), which based on certain conditions decides which all modules should be built. After finding out such modules how can I trigger `build` (or any other task) on submodules.

One way I can think of is re-writing settings.gradle and mention only those modules which are eligible for build. But this does not seem a good idea. Let me know if there is a better approach, or I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Your plugin should provide a task which will be invoked on the command line by a plugin user. All task you detect to be run should have defined a dependency on the aforementioned task. This way they will run during the build.

Comment: @Opal thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it and let you know.